# tkinter Listbox does not show complete content and works only once

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am measuring objects through images from 3 cameras simultaneously (using `multiprocessing`), and right now I am stuck in the GUI. I have created a button which when pressed performs image processing and calculates the measurements but there are 2 problems:

1. The button works only once and if it is pressed again program does not respond.
2. In the button function, there is a `Listbox` created to display values in the form of list but it shows only the first 2 measurements while others are not displayed.

Here is the code for the main window:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("CVIM")

Lb1 = tk.Listbox(window)
Lb1.insert(1, "Length=")
Lb1.insert(2, "Width=")
Lb1.insert(3, "front length=")
Lb1.insert(4, "Front width=")
Lb1.insert(5, "back length=")
Lb1.insert(6, "Back width=")

Lb1.pack(side='left')

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = int(ch*1.5), height = int(cw/1.5)) # bg='blue'
canvas.pack(side='top')
tk.Label(text="IMAGES").pack(side='top')

tk.Button(window, text="Quit", command=exit).pack(side='bottom')
tk.Button(window, text="snapshot", command=lambda: snapshot(window,canvas)).pack(side='bottom')
CheckVar = tk.IntVar()
tk.Checkbutton(window, text = "Preview", variable = CheckVar, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=10, width = 0).pack(side='bottom')

window.mainloop()
```

Here is the code of snapshot button:

```
def snapshot(window, canvas):
    imgs=[];
    for ind,que in enumerate(queues):
        frame = que.get()
        imageRGB=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        imgs.append(imageRGB)

    #Imageprocessing code here
    dims=[tL,tW,fL,fW,bL,bW]

    Lb2 = tk.Listbox(window)

    for ind,measurements in enumerate(dims):
        Lb2.insert(ind, "{:.2f}mm".format(measurements) )
    Lb2.pack(side='left')
```

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZFna.png) of what I get when the button works for the first time.

Comment: Shouldn't matter, but try using using `tk.END` as the first argument when you add lines by calling `ListBox.insert()` (instead of an integer index value).

Comment: Every time the `snapshot()` button callback function is called, a new `Listbox` is created. I think you need to get rid of the previous one. That will involve something like defining `Lb2` to be a module-level variable with the value `None` and, at the beginning of the function declaring `global Lb2` so it's not assumed to be a local variable, and finally the inside the function saying `if Lb2 is not None: Lb2.destroy()` all before creating another one. It's not clear why the `imgs` list is being created (that's the least of the problems).

Comment: yeah I just figured it, there was a que making the program stuck so it is resolved but gor every click it creats new listbox

Comment: However the listbox still not showing complete content imgs list is created to store 3 images of 3 different cameras

Comment: Without a [mre] it's difficult to help. Minimal would mean getting rid of the `cv2` stuff since that has no bearing on the problem. Consider only having one `Listbox` and updating its contents when the button is pressed — that would make more sense user-interface-wise as well IMO.

Comment: how can I do that ? plus when I use .place method it works fine but .pack method does that only

Comment: `Listbox`es have methods for manipulating and updating their contents. Here's some fairly decent [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190323174019id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html) on it. There's a little documentation on the Place, Pack, and Grid "Geometry Managers" [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/). As far as specific problems you're having with them goes, you'll have to post a specific question. Try to make any code posted as simple as possible that will illustrate the issue.